# Remove all occurrences of a string from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I would like to split an array at all occurences of a string in an array, in Javascript. For example:

```
var array = ["fast", "red", "race"];
var string = "The fast red race car drove fast.";

var replacedArray = [];
```

I would like end up with `replacedArray` being equal to: `["The "," car drove ","."]`

I've looked around for a while, but I can't find anything. I assume it would be done with a `split()` and `join()`, but I have no idea beyond that.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I'd suggest starting with `for` or `forEach`.

Comment: I think spliting the string using a regular expression of the target words would give you exactly the output you want.

Comment: @charlietfl, Umm.. This isn't a homework question.
@tadman, Ok. But could I use `split()`or how would I do it after that?

Comment: @fubar, how would I split it? If I need to put it in a for loop, how would I know how many times to repeat the loop?

Comment: Well when you ask without showing any research effort whatsoever then it appears like one. Read that link anyway as the principles are the same regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example using the `String.prototype.split` to separate the sentence into separate tokens based on the word(s) for removal, and then `Array.prototype.filter` to remove empty / space only strings.

```js
const remove = ["fast", "red", "race"];
const string = "The fast red race car drove fast.";

const result = string
  .split(new RegExp(remove.join("|")))
  .filter(token => !!token.trim());
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

So this seems like something fundamental I would try to work out on my own, so I'm not going to be sending any code. Instead, I am going to guide you in the direction to which you could solve this problem. I would use the split() function in order to break up the string (sentence). Then using a nested for loop you loop through the newly created array from the split function and check to see if each element in the array is in that original delimiter array. If it finds that the two elements are the same then you need to remove, or not add to a new array. Whichever one you like. From that, you should be able to have an array or some data type in which you have the words that are not in the delimiter array.